# Rgdal package install: projects.h: No such file or directory (error)

Tags: r, rgdal

I'm trying to install `Rgdal` package on my local server (no connected to internet). when I ran `install.packages("rgdal_1.2-15.tar.gz","/usr/lib64/R/library/",repos=NULL)` I got an error `inverser.c:4:22: error: projects.h: No such file or directory`

this is the out put of install process:

```
* installing *source* package ‘rgdal’ ...
** package ‘rgdal’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
configure: CC: gcc -m64 -std=gnu99
configure: CXX: g++ -m64
configure: rgdal: 1.2-15
checking for /usr/bin/svnversion... no
configure: svn revision: 691
checking for gdal-config... /usr/bin/gdal-config
checking gdal-config usability... yes
configure: GDAL: 1.8.1
checking GDAL version >= 1.6.3... yes
checking gdal: linking with --libs only... yes
checking GDAL: /usr/share/gdal/pcs.csv readable... yes
configure: -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic -fpic -fPIC  -I/usr/include/gdal
checking proj_api.h presence and usability... yes
checking PROJ.4 version: ... 4.8.0
checking PROJ.4: epsg found and readable... yes
checking PROJ.4: conus found and readable... yes
configure: Package CPP flags:  -I/usr/include/gdal
configure: Package LIBS:  -lgdal -lproj
configure: creating ./config.status
config.status: creating src/Makevars
** libs
g++ -m64 -std=c++0x -I/usr/include/R -DNDEBUG -I/usr/include/gdal -I/usr/local/include -I"/usr/lib64/R/library/sp/include"   -fpic  -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic -c OGR_write.cpp -o OGR_write.o
g++ -m64 -std=c++0x -I/usr/include/R -DNDEBUG -I/usr/include/gdal -I/usr/local/include -I"/usr/lib64/R/library/sp/include"   -fpic  -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic -c gdal-bindings.cpp -o gdal-bindings.o
gcc -m64 -std=gnu99 -I/usr/include/R -DNDEBUG -I/usr/include/gdal -I/usr/local/include -I"/usr/lib64/R/library/sp/include"   -fpic  -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic -fpic -fPIC   -c init.c -o init.o
gcc -m64 -std=gnu99 -I/usr/include/R -DNDEBUG -I/usr/include/gdal -I/usr/local/include -I"/usr/lib64/R/library/sp/include"   -fpic  -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic -fpic -fPIC   -c inverser.c -o inverser.o
inverser.c:4:22: error: projects.h: No such file or directory
inverser.c:6: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘*’ token
make: *** [inverser.o] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘rgdal’
* removing ‘/usr/lib64/R/library/rgdal’
Warning message:
In install.packages("/data/ZUY10/Repo/R/rgdal_1.2-15.tar.gz", "/usr/lib64/R/library/",  :
  installation of package ‘/data/ZUY10/Repo/R/rgdal_1.2-15.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status
```

What I did before this step:

Since my server is local, I had to install all package "dependencies" manually in my local server, So I installed like 30 packages manually which PROJ.4 and Gdal are principal as you can see [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rgdal/index.html).

What do I miss here to install the RGDAL PACKAGE?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The header `projects.h` comes from PROJ.4. Where is that header file located on your system? You can pass this location to the `configure` script via `--with-proj-include=DIR`, i.e.

```
install.packages("rgdal_1.2-15.tar.gz",
                 "/usr/lib64/R/library/",
                 repos=NULL,
                 configure.args="--with-proj-include=DIR")
```

A check for `projects.h` being found has been added to `rgdal` only [recently](https://r-forge.r-project.org/scm/viewvc.php?view=rev&root=rgdal&revision=721).

Comment: Thanks a lot your question has saved my day

Comment: I still have a problem with this package, check this out please : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50064673/cannot-install-rgdal-package-in-local-server-an-irrecoverable-exception-occurre

Answer (score 0):

I have also faced above issue on `RHEL7.7` upon doing multiple search. I resolved it as below:

```
#cd /opt

#wget http://download.osgeo.org/gdal/2.0.1/gdal-2.0.1.tar.gz

#./configure

#make

#make install

#echo "/usr/local/lib" >> /etc/ld.so.conf.d/libgdal-x86_64.conf

#ldconfig

#yum install  proj.x86_64 proj-devel.x86_64 proj-epsg.x86_64 proj-nad.x86_64
```

Hope this helps.