# cannot install rgdal package in local server, An irrecoverable exception occurred. R is aborting now...[ERROR: loading failed]

Tags: r, rgdal

I'm trying to install Rgdal package, all packages and their dependancies I've installed them manuelly since my server is offline, I have struggled with those dependancies for a long time. but now I think I fix the problem, but my problem now I think has came from R, I cannot even figure out what's happen. this is the out put I gut when I run the commande `install.packages("rgdal_1.2-15.tar.gz","/usr/lib64/R/library/",repos=NULL,configure.args="--with-proj-include=/usr/proj49/include/")` on R:

```
* installing *source* package ‘rgdal’ ...
** package ‘rgdal’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
configure: CC: gcc -m64 -std=gnu99
configure: CXX: g++ -m64
configure: rgdal: 1.2-15
checking for /usr/bin/svnversion... no
configure: svn revision: 691
checking for gdal-config... /usr/bin/gdal-config
checking gdal-config usability... yes
configure: GDAL: 1.8.1
checking GDAL version >= 1.6.3... yes
checking gdal: linking with --libs only... yes
checking GDAL: /usr/share/gdal/pcs.csv readable... yes
configure: -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic -fpic -fPIC -I/usr/proj49/include/
checking proj_api.h presence and usability... yes
checking PROJ.4 version: ... > 4.8.0
/usr/bin/ld: warning: libproj.so.12, needed by /usr/lib64/libogdi.so.3, may conflict with libproj.so.0
./configure: line 2112: 27095 Segmentation fault      (core dumped) ./proj_conf_test2
checking PROJ.4: epsg found and readable... yes
/usr/bin/ld: warning: libproj.so.12, needed by /usr/lib64/libogdi.so.3, may conflict with libproj.so.0
./configure: line 2187: 27107 Segmentation fault      (core dumped) ./proj_conf_test3
checking PROJ.4: conus found and readable... yes
configure: Package CPP flags:  -I/usr/include/gdal -I/usr/proj49/include/
configure: Package LIBS:  -lgdal -lproj
configure: creating ./config.status
config.status: creating src/Makevars
** libs
g++ -m64 -std=c++0x -I/usr/include/R -DNDEBUG -I/usr/include/gdal -I/usr/proj49/include/ -I/usr/local/include -I"/usr/lib64/R/library/sp/include"   -fpic  -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic -c OGR_write.cpp -o OGR_write.o
g++ -m64 -std=c++0x -I/usr/include/R -DNDEBUG -I/usr/include/gdal -I/usr/proj49/include/ -I/usr/local/include -I"/usr/lib64/R/library/sp/include"   -fpic  -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic -c gdal-bindings.cpp -o gdal-bindings.o
gcc -m64 -std=gnu99 -I/usr/include/R -DNDEBUG -I/usr/include/gdal -I/usr/proj49/include/ -I/usr/local/include -I"/usr/lib64/R/library/sp/include"   -fpic  -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic -fpic -fPIC   -c init.c -o init.o
gcc -m64 -std=gnu99 -I/usr/include/R -DNDEBUG -I/usr/include/gdal -I/usr/proj49/include/ -I/usr/local/include -I"/usr/lib64/R/library/sp/include"   -fpic  -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic -fpic -fPIC   -c inverser.c -o inverser.o
gcc -m64 -std=gnu99 -I/usr/include/R -DNDEBUG -I/usr/include/gdal -I/usr/proj49/include/ -I/usr/local/include -I"/usr/lib64/R/library/sp/include"   -fpic  -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic -fpic -fPIC   -c local_stubs.c -o local_stubs.o
g++ -m64 -std=c++0x -I/usr/include/R -DNDEBUG -I/usr/include/gdal -I/usr/proj49/include/ -I/usr/local/include -I"/usr/lib64/R/library/sp/include"   -fpic  -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic -c ogr_geom.cpp -o ogr_geom.o
ogr_geom.cpp: In function ‘SEXPREC* R_OGR_CAPI_features(SEXPREC*, SEXPREC*, SEXPREC*)’:
ogr_geom.cpp:39: warning: ‘mp_count_k0’ may be used uninitialized in this function
gcc -m64 -std=gnu99 -I/usr/include/R -DNDEBUG -I/usr/include/gdal -I/usr/proj49/include/ -I/usr/local/include -I"/usr/lib64/R/library/sp/include"   -fpic  -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic -fpic -fPIC   -c ogr_polygons.c -o ogr_polygons.o
g++ -m64 -std=c++0x -I/usr/include/R -DNDEBUG -I/usr/include/gdal -I/usr/proj49/include/ -I/usr/local/include -I"/usr/lib64/R/library/sp/include"   -fpic  -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic -c ogr_proj.cpp -o ogr_proj.o
g++ -m64 -std=c++0x -I/usr/include/R -DNDEBUG -I/usr/include/gdal -I/usr/proj49/include/ -I/usr/local/include -I"/usr/lib64/R/library/sp/include"   -fpic  -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic -c ogrdrivers.cpp -o ogrdrivers.o
g++ -m64 -std=c++0x -I/usr/include/R -DNDEBUG -I/usr/include/gdal -I/usr/proj49/include/ -I/usr/local/include -I"/usr/lib64/R/library/sp/include"   -fpic  -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic -c ogrsource.cpp -o ogrsource.o
ogrsource.cpp: In function ‘SEXPREC* ogrReadListColumn(OGRLayer*, SEXPREC*, int, int, int)’:
ogrsource.cpp:651: warning: unused variable ‘DINT_MAX’
ogrsource.cpp:652: warning: unused variable ‘DINT_MIN’
g++ -m64 -std=c++0x -I/usr/include/R -DNDEBUG -I/usr/include/gdal -I/usr/proj49/include/ -I/usr/local/include -I"/usr/lib64/R/library/sp/include"   -fpic  -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic -c projectit.cpp -o projectit.o
g++ -m64 -std=c++0x -shared -L/usr/lib64/R/lib -o rgdal.so OGR_write.o gdal-bindings.o init.o inverser.o local_stubs.o ogr_geom.o ogr_polygons.o ogr_proj.o ogrdrivers.o ogrsource.o projectit.o -lgdal -lproj -L/usr/lib64/R/lib -lR
installing to /usr/lib64/R/library/rgdal/libs
** R
** data
** inst
** preparing package for lazy loading
** help
*** installing help indices
  converting help for package ‘rgdal’
    finding HTML links ... done
    CRS-class                               html
    GDALDataset-class                       html
    GDALDriver-class                        html
    GDALMajorObject-class                   html
    GDALRasterBand-class                    html
    GDALReadOnlyDataset-class               html
    GDALReadOnlyDataset-methods             html
    GDALTransientDataset-class              html
    GridsDatums                             html
    RGB2PCT                                 html
    SGDF2PCT                                html
    SpatialGDAL-class                       html
    closeDataset-methods                    html
    displayDataset                          html
    llgrid                                  html
Rd warning: /tmp/RtmpKNPZgP/R.INSTALL68d7595014d0/rgdal/man/llgrid.Rd:11: missing file link ‘Spatial’
Rd warning: /tmp/RtmpKNPZgP/R.INSTALL68d7595014d0/rgdal/man/llgrid.Rd:16: missing file link ‘gridat’
Rd warning: /tmp/RtmpKNPZgP/R.INSTALL68d7595014d0/rgdal/man/llgrid.Rd:17: missing file link ‘gridat’
    make_EPSG                               html
    nor2k                                   html
    projInfo                                html
    project                                 html
    readGDAL                                html
Rd warning: /tmp/RtmpKNPZgP/R.INSTALL68d7595014d0/rgdal/man/readGDAL.Rd:136: missing file link ‘flipVertical’
    readOGR                                 html
    showWKT                                 html
    spTransform-methods                     html
    wrappers                                html
    writeOGR                                html
** building package indices
** installing vignettes
** testing if installed package can be loaded
sh: line 1: 28842 Segmentation fault      (core dumped) '/usr/lib64/R/bin/R' --no-save --slave 2>&1 < '/tmp/RtmpKNPZgP/file68d75bc50ad1'

 *** caught segfault ***
address 0x20, cause 'memory not mapped'

Traceback:
 1: .Call("PROJ4_proj_def_dat_Installed", PACKAGE = "rgdal")
 2: assign("has_proj_def.dat", .Call("PROJ4_proj_def_dat_Installed",     PACKAGE = "rgdal"), envir = .RGDAL_CACHE)
 3: fun(libname, pkgname)
 4: doTryCatch(return(expr), name, parentenv, handler)
 5: tryCatchOne(expr, names, parentenv, handlers[[1L]])
 6: tryCatchList(expr, classes, parentenv, handlers)
 7: tryCatch(fun(libname, pkgname), error = identity)
 8: runHook(".onLoad", env, package.lib, package)
 9: loadNamespace(package, lib.loc)
10: doTryCatch(return(expr), name, parentenv, handler)
11: tryCatchOne(expr, names, parentenv, handlers[[1L]])
12: tryCatchList(expr, classes, parentenv, handlers)
13: tryCatch(expr, error = function(e) {    call <- conditionCall(e)    if (!is.null(call)) {        if (identical(call[[1L]], quote(doTryCatch)))             call <- sys.call(-4L)        dcall <- deparse(call)[1L]        prefix <- paste("Error in", dcall, ": ")        LONG <- 75L        msg <- conditionMessage(e)        sm <- strsplit(msg, "\n")[[1L]]        w <- 14L + nchar(dcall, type = "w") + nchar(sm[1L], type = "w")        if (is.na(w))             w <- 14L + nchar(dcall, type = "b") + nchar(sm[1L],                 type = "b")        if (w > LONG)             prefix <- paste0(prefix, "\n  ")    }    else prefix <- "Error : "    msg <- paste0(prefix, conditionMessage(e), "\n")    .Internal(seterrmessage(msg[1L]))    if (!silent && identical(getOption("show.error.messages"),         TRUE)) {        cat(msg, file = stderr())        .Internal(printDeferredWarnings())    }    invisible(structure(msg, class = "try-error", condition = e))})
14: try({    attr(package, "LibPath") <- which.lib.loc    ns <- loadNamespace(package, lib.loc)    env <- attachNamespace(ns, pos = pos, deps)})
15: library(pkg_name, lib.loc = lib, character.only = TRUE, logical.return = TRUE)
16: withCallingHandlers(expr, packageStartupMessage = function(c) invokeRestart("muffleMessage"))
17: suppressPackageStartupMessages(library(pkg_name, lib.loc = lib,     character.only = TRUE, logical.return = TRUE))
18: doTryCatch(return(expr), name, parentenv, handler)
19: tryCatchOne(expr, names, parentenv, handlers[[1L]])
20: tryCatchList(expr, classes, parentenv, handlers)
21: tryCatch(expr, error = function(e) {    call <- conditionCall(e)    if (!is.null(call)) {        if (identical(call[[1L]], quote(doTryCatch)))             call <- sys.call(-4L)        dcall <- deparse(call)[1L]        prefix <- paste("Error in", dcall, ": ")        LONG <- 75L        msg <- conditionMessage(e)        sm <- strsplit(msg, "\n")[[1L]]        w <- 14L + nchar(dcall, type = "w") + nchar(sm[1L], type = "w")        if (is.na(w))             w <- 14L + nchar(dcall, type = "b") + nchar(sm[1L],                 type = "b")        if (w > LONG)             prefix <- paste0(prefix, "\n  ")    }    else prefix <- "Error : "    msg <- paste0(prefix, conditionMessage(e), "\n")    .Internal(seterrmessage(msg[1L]))    if (!silent && identical(getOption("show.error.messages"),         TRUE)) {        cat(msg, file = stderr())        .Internal(printDeferredWarnings())    }    invisible(structure(msg, class = "try-error", condition = e))})
22: try(suppressPackageStartupMessages(library(pkg_name, lib.loc = lib,     character.only = TRUE, logical.return = TRUE)))
23: tools:::.test_load_package("rgdal", "/usr/lib64/R/library")
An irrecoverable exception occurred. R is aborting now ...
ERROR: loading failed
* removing ‘/usr/lib64/R/library/rgdal’
Warning message:
In install.packages("rgdal_1.2-15.tar.gz", "/usr/lib64/R/library/",  :
  installation of package ‘rgdal_1.2-15.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status
```

**Update**:

even with a newer version of Rgdal `install.packages("rgdal_1.2-18.tar.gz","/usr/lib64/R/library/",repos=NULL,configure.args="--with-proj-include=/usr/proj49/include/")`, I got the same error

Comment: are you installing on linux?

Comment: Yes, on linux RedHat 6

Comment: I spent a lot of time trying to install on linux centos and the conclusion was that rGdal and similar GIS packages cannot be installed on linux centos.

Comment: @Seymour such a bad news, I have spent a whole week to fix this, what a frustration

Comment: Let s see what other people say

Comment: The warnings and segfaults during configure are interesting. Which versions of libproject.so do you have installed?

Answer (score 1):

Please follow the below steps to install gdal on RHEL/CentOS 7

```
wget http://download.osgeo.org/gdal/2.0.1/gdal-2.0.1.tar.gz

./configure

make

make install
```